# Prevent map click event when clicking on Leaflet control

Tags: leaflet

I have added a slider from antd to Leaflet map, but when I clicked to slider it's also run map onclick event. I have tried to stop propagation but it only works with button.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<div
    id='map'
    style={{
        width: '100%',
        height: "100vh",
        position: "relative",
      }}
>
   <div onClick={(e) => {
      if(e.target === e.currentTarget){
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
            e.nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation();
      }
  }}>
         <div className='leaflet-control' // this classname help overlay the map
            style={{
                width: '100%', bottom: "10px", left: "0%", position: 'absolute'
            }}>
            <Layout
                style={{
                    width: "23%",
                    margin: 'auto',
                    padding: 7,
                    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF'
                }}
            >
                <div style={{ fontSize: 14 }}>{title}</div>
                <Slider style={{ color: 'gray' }} defaultValue={100} 
                  tipFormatter={(value) => `${value}%`}
                    onChange={onChangeOpacity} />
            </Layout>
        </div >
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to `stopPropagation` of the `mousedown` and `mouseup` events.

In React:

```
<div onMouseDown={(e) => e.stopPropagation()} onMouseUp={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}>
  ...
</div>
```